# Javascript - How to change a component's property?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Supposed I have the following code:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(
        componentType, 
        {
            "property1":"something", 
            "property2":"something2"
        },
        null, 
        null, 
        $get("element"
    ));
});
```

How could I change property1 of this created component in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*ASP.NET Component*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397516%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) must be defined to provide setters, such that

```
component.set_property1("new value")
```

updates the corresponding "property1" value. Setters are how the properties are initially set, so not having them will actually break other aspects of the Component. See [Creating Client Components and Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386565%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for additional information.

Then it's just a matter of "remembering" (i.e. store in a variable) the Component returned from the [`$create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165447%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) invocation; where the Client/Component ID is known `$find` can be useful. Since the ASP.NET system is quite complex, I would recommend *not* manually using `$create`, but rather only interact with the component system through the corresponding [ASP.NET AJAX] Web Controls.

---

In summary,

```
$create(t, { "property1":"something" }, ..);
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
var component = $create(t, {}, ..);
component.set_property1("something");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using Tampermonkey to inject my own javascript into another person's code, so I cannot rewrite the actual making of the component. There is no other way?

Comment: The [`$find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397441(v=vs.100).aspx) method to can be used to obtain a component - it requires the the *ID* of the element supplied initially to create the component.